# wxPython adding frames with multiple selection option

Tags: wxpython

[image]I need to create a Python frame as shown in the attached picutre.

Let me know how to accomplish it.

[image]

There are totally 3 blocks..
1.header 
2.Navigation
3.Main content..

Navigation block should be mutiple frames..each time you select a option it needs to change..

It has to be more like a menu navigation

import random
import wx

#

class TabPanel1(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def **init**(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.**init**(self, parent=parent)

```
    colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
    self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

panel1 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

panel1gs = wx.GridSizer(2,2,1,2)

panel1gs.AddMany( [ (wx.StaticText(self,label='FirstLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
        (wx.StaticText(self,label='SecondLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
        (wx.StaticText(self,label='ThirdLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
        (wx.StaticText(self,label='FourthLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND)
        ] )

panel1.SetSizer(panel1gs)

panel2 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5042')

panel3 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
panel3.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5042')

    btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
sizer.Add(panel1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
sizer.Add(panel2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
sizer.Add(panel3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

class TabPanel2(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def **init**(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.**init**(self, parent=parent)

```
    colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
    self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

    btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

#

class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    """Constructor"""        
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                      "Notebook Tutorial",
                      size=(800,600)
                      )
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
    tabOne = TabPanel1(notebook)
    notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

    tabTwo = TabPanel2(notebook)
    notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Layout()

    self.Show()
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------

if **name** == "**main**":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()

Latest changes
Newcode.py

```
import random
import wx


########################################################################
class PanelTextCombo(wx.Panel):
     def __init__(self,parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent,size=(400,100))

    self.SetBackgroundColour('blue')

    panel1gs = wx.GridSizer(2,2,1,2)

    panel1gs.AddMany( [ (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FirstLabel'),0),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='SecondLabel'),0),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='ThirdLabel'),0),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FourthLabel'),0)
            ] )



    panel1.SetSizer(panel1gs)

class TabPanel1(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        #self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('RED')

    #panel1 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    #panel1.SetBackgroundColour('blue')

    #panel1gs = wx.GridSizer(2,2,1,2)

    #panel1gs.AddMany( [ (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FirstLabel'),0),
    #       (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='SecondLabel'),0),
    #       (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='ThirdLabel'),0),
    #       (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FourthLabel'),0)
    #       ] )

    #panel1.SetSizer(panel1gs)
    panel1 = PanelTextCombo(TabPanel1)
    #panel2 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    #panel2.SetBackgroundColour('green')

    #panel3 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    #panel3.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5042')

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    sizer.Add(panel1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    #sizer.Add(panel2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    #sizer.Add(panel3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class TabPanel2(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(800,600)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel1(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

        tabTwo = TabPanel2(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I think what you want is a [wx.Notebook](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Notebooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wx.StaticText for the top part as a label, then use a wx.Notebook (or one of the other "book" widgets) for the rest. See the following tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/15/wxpython-a-simple-notebook-example/

Comment: I created a Notebook..added 3 panels within it..and it worked..but my requirement is..1st panel within it should contain 3 panels and within each of 3 panels, I will add different controls

Comment: You can put three panels into a sizer or you could use a nested Notebook.

Comment: Can you check the above piece of code..Im trying to set a sizer for panel1 in page1 but for somereason its nor working

Comment: I got the answer..I was not setting the new buttons parent panel is panel1.